# Enable Codelens on VisualStudio.com

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, codelens

I hosted my TFS on visualstudio.com but I can't seems to find the tfsconfig on my local machine and unable to enable codeindex from the web interface. Anyone has similar issue?

Comment: Ehm... what is the downvote for?

Comment: Any word on this?  Using VS2013 Ultimate Update 3 with VSO (TFS) and not getting Code Lens.  Shouldn't this work, especially if it works OK with VSO (Git)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe CodeLens works against VSO yet.

Comment: It also doesn't work against TFS-Git repositories.  But I expect MS is working on supporting both these scenarios.

Comment: Codelens for Git is coming with Visual Studio 2013 Update 3: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/05/23/code-lens-for-git-in-visual-studio-2013-ultimate-update-3.aspx

Answer (score 2):

### Update

[April 17th this year Codelens is now live for all accounts on Visual Studio Online.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/04/17/general-availability-of-codelens-in-visual-studio-online.aspx)

Requires:

- **Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with update 4** or higher for TFVC
- **Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with update 3** or higher for Git
- **Visual Studio 2015 Professional** or higher for TFVC and Git

In case this doesn't work:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio.
2. Delete all the cached data in the folder `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services\5.0\`
3. Restart Visual Studio and re-open the solution from Visual Studio Online.

Answer (score 1):

There is an update!

Currently CodeLens is being developed for VSO, currently in Public Preview for what I have read so far, in US and West-Europe.

**Requirements:**

1. Be using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 4, or Visual Studio 2015
   (Preview or later version).
2. Check your code into Team Foundation
   Version Control in Visual Studio Online.

Just updated to VS Ultimate Update 4, already had a solution setup on VSO, works great as expected.

**troubleshoot, CodeLens not appearing?**

1. Close all Visual Studio Instances.
2. Remove the cache from %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio Services\5.0\
3. Reopen Visual Studio, open the solution from Visual Studio Online.

I'm not sure if it was necessary to do this for me, I did it, looked like it had no effect and the codeLens still didn't appear. While I was typing out a new question they suddenly appeared. So it could take a few minutes.

Source: [CodeLens in VSO is now in public preview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/03/11/codelens-in-visual-studio-online-is-now-in-public-preview-for-europe-region.aspx?utm_content=bufferb290a&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)